# flutter Child1 send data1 to Parent which forwards data1 to Child2

Tags: flutter

I have a Form widget with multiple TextFormFields.

As flutter is not that readable I am putting even simple form fields each in its own widget.

No idea wether this is bad...

So I wrapped a TextFormField and a Radio Button group each in its own statefull widget.

Now both can **NOT** communicate anymore together.

When I change a value on the Radio button widget the Text Form field widget should change its value too.

How can I do that?

Actually I have a parent with 2 children and they need to share data.

I havent found a communiction strategy in flutter for that advanced use case... working with 2 functions here seem really a bad and cumbersome idea...

In angular I used a shared singleton service for such scenarios. Exists there something similar in flutter?

Comment: Could you post some code? usually the general idea is wrapping these widget in a Form that has a GlobalKey<FormState> and on each of these widgets inside a form provide a `onSaved` function to update some kind of values you need

Comment: As I wrote... a simple function passing down and calling there will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use singletons with get_it package https://pub.dev/packages/get_it or use provider to send data between pages

Comment: Is that common practice in flutter using a shared service?

Comment: yes it is either this provider pattern or Bloc pattern with Streams

Comment: thanks today i have read about provider where I also saw get_it mentioned!